# Изменить состав заказа в битриксе при импорте из 1с

Tags: битрикс, 1с, импорт

Из 1с прилетают измененные заказы, не могу найти в коде где формируется состав заказа из xml файла.

Comment: Мы сами не знаем можете вы найти в коде где формируется состав заказа из *xml* файла или нет. `1с` к счастью не знаю, т.ч могу только посоветовать вам приложить  СВОЮ попытку решения.

Comment: В этом то и дело, я ищу функцию/класс который этим занимается в ядре битрикса.

Comment: см https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/magazin/export_zakaz/sale_export_1c.php

Comment: в этом sale.export.1c в component.php при mode = import отправляются данные, они проходят через класс CSaleOrderLoader (/bitrix/modules/sale/general/order_loader.php). Я перерыл весь этот файл, нашел только одно упоминание которое на что-то влияет в nodeHandler(), а именно $r = $importer->process($documentData); дальше следы теряются...

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам себе.

в функции

```
private function fillBasket(Sale\BasketBase $basket, array $basketItems){}
```

перебирается массив элементов из xml, добавил такой костыль для проверки

```
$item["ID"] = rand(1,10);
```

Всё заработало как требовалось, унаследовался от функции и запихнул в init.php

Как временное решение - сойдет.